# How i can get Ubuntu terminal's list from Qt

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, terminal-emulator

In my app i want to open ssh in terminal-emulator for user. Now i'am using QProcess like this:

```
QProcess _localhostConnection;
_localhostConnection.start(QString("gnome-terminal"), QStringList("--command=ssh 127.0.0.1"));
```

But the problem is there can be no gnome-terminal on another computer. Another computer has Ubuntu. How can i get installed terminal's list in Qt on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `x-terminal-emulator` instead. Almost all Debian-based systems use the `update-alternatives` package (in conjunction with virtual packages like `x-terminal-emulator`) to bookkeep programs with similar functions, such as Internet browsers, editors, command shells, et cetra. Calling `x-terminal-emulator` will launch the default terminal emulator set by the user.
Read more about `update-alternatives` here: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html

However, hardcoding `--command=ssh 127.0.0.1` isn't very wise if you are aiming to support all terminal emulators. XTerm, for example, won't accept that parameter syntax.

Comment: Thanks. `update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator` command seems relevant for my purposes. We can parse this command output and get terminals list.